# How to pass CSS from CSS module as prop in Next.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, css-modules

I am trying to apply CSS on a component called `Cards`. I want to apply the CSS on the `#image_div` div. My code is as follows:

`team.module.css`:

```
.grid_container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,auto);
}
.image #image_div{
   border-radius:100%;
    margin: 30vh;
}
```

`index.js`:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import Div from "../../components/Div";
import Cards from "../../components/Cards";
import styles from "../../styles/team.module.css";
import xyz from "../../public/xyz.jpeg"

export default function Team(){
    return (
        <Div>
            <div className={`${styles.grid_container}`}>
                <Cards url={xyz} title={"XYZ"} className={styles.image}></Cards>
            </div>
        </Div>
    );
}
```

`Cards.js`:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import styles from "../styles/components/Card.module.css";

export default function Cards({title,url,width,height,alt,description,className}) {
  return (
    <Card className={`card col-xs-12 col-sm-4 ${styles.Card} ${className?className:null}`}>
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-center" id="image_div">
            <Image
            variant="top"
            src={url}
            width={width}
            height={height}
            alt={alt}
            className="img-card"
            />
      </div>
      <Card.Body className="card-content">
        <Card.Title className="card-title text-center">{title}</Card.Title>
        <Card.Text className="text-center">{description}</Card.Text>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

But when I inspected the `#image_div` the CSS is not applied to it. What am I doing wrong here? I want to apply the CSS defined in the `team.module.css` without defining the same CSS in the `Card.module.css` file (which contains CSS for `Cards.js`).

Answer (score 1):

Just like the class selectors, the `#image_div` selector also gets namespaced by CSS Modules.

You have to use `:global()` on the selector to switch to global scope and properly target `#image_div`.

```js
.image :global(#image_div) {
    border-radius:100%;
    margin: 30vh;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to apply it globaly because I have used the same cards on other sections of the home page . I don't want those sections to get effected by it

Comment: It should only affect the `Card`s in the `Team` component because of the additional scoped `.image` selector.